# Ansible pass fact between hosts in the same playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm trying to pass a fact from host1 to host2, but when ansible reaches hosts2 it returns "undefined variable":

```yaml
- name: some playbook
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact1: "foo"

- hosts: host2
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ fact1 }}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`set_fact` module sets host variables, You could access to those variable with `hostvars`.

```yaml
- name: some playbook
  gather_facts: no
  hosts: host1
  tasks:

  - set_fact:
      fact1: "foo"

- hosts: host2
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:

  - debug:
      msg: "{{ hostvars['host1']['fact1'] }}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work I'm getting "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: "hostvars['host1']" is undefined"

Comment: this is exactly what i needed, to grab multiple hosts data to combine for use on each host it ran on.  thanks!  
@bugs bunny, i think maybe you didnt specify your real hostname in place of `host1`?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this use case might be solved in three steps. Create, share, and use the variables. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
```

the playbook works as expected

```yaml
- name: Run single host and create facts
  hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact1: foo

- name: Share facts among all hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact1: "{{ hostvars.host1.fact1 }}"
      run_once: true

- name: Use shared facts
  hosts: host2
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: fact1
```

---

If you extend the use case to "passing facts from a group of hosts to another group of hosts" the problem is how to efficiently share the variables? Create a playbook dynamically. For example, given the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
host1
host2
host3
host4
```

let host1 and host4 create the variables and host2 and host3 use them. Create the template

```yaml
shell> cat share-vars.yml.j2
- name: Share facts among all hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
{% for i in share_vars %}
        {{ i.var }}: "{{ lbr }} hostvars.{{ i.host }}.{{ i.var }} {{ rbr }}"
{% endfor %}
      run_once: true
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat create-share-vars.yml
- name: Create playbook share-vars.yml
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    share_vars:
      - {host: host1, var: fact1}
      - {host: host4, var: fact4}
    lbr: "{{ '{{' }}"
    rbr: "{{ '}}' }}"
  tasks:
    - template:
        src: share-vars.yml.j2
        dest: share-vars.yml
```

gives

```yaml
shell> cat share-vars.yml
- name: Share facts among all hosts
  hosts: all
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact1: "{{ hostvars.host1.fact1 }}"
        fact4: "{{ hostvars.host4.fact4 }}"
      run_once: true
```

Import this playbook, for example

```yaml
shell> cat playbook.yml
- hosts: host1
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact1: foo

- hosts: host4
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        fact4: bar

- import_playbook: share-vars.yml

- hosts: host2,host3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: fact1
    - debug:
        var: fact4
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
PLAY [host2,host3] *********************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  fact1: foo
ok: [host3] => 
  fact1: foo

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host2] => 
  fact4: bar
ok: [host3] => 
  fact4: bar
```

---

Notes

- What is the advantage of the template? Change the variable *share_vars* and rebuild the imported play when needed. Don't change the code.
- In Ansible, it's not possible to substitute the left-hand side of an assignment, i.e. no [symbolic reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(computer_science)#Symbolic_references).
- Put "gather_facts: false" to the plays if you don't need it.